# Using pytest patch decorator to test ray actors remote function

Tags: pytest, ray, pytest-mock

I'm trying to run unit test for a ray remote function. I am using a @patch decorator to patch the remote function. The

foo.py

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def bar(self):
        self.value = 100
        print("In original method")
        assert False
```

test_foo.py

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest
import unittest
import ray

from tests.foo import Foo


@pytest.fixture
def ray_fixture():
    print("Initializing ray")
    if not ray.is_initialized():
        ray.init()
    yield None
    print("Terminating ray")
    ray.shutdown()


def fake_bar(self):
    print("In fake method")
    assert True


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("ray_fixture")
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test cases for Foo module"""

    @patch("foo.Foo.bar", new=fake_bar)
    def test_bar(self):
        Foo().bar()

    @patch("foo.Foo.bar", new=fake_bar)
    def test_bar_remote(self):
        foo_actor = ray.remote(Foo).remote()
        obj_ref = foo_actor.bar.remote()
        ray.get(obj_ref)
```

The test `test_bar` passes and `test_bar_remote` fails.
If I use `ray.init(local_mode=True)` then both tests pass. I can not use `local_mode=True` due to other limitations.

How can we patch ray actor's remote method using @patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative. Subclass `Foo` with a stubbed/mocked implementation and use it in ray. That way, the `Foo` class would be intact, you would only update those that needs to be mocked e.g. the method `bar()`.

test_foo.py

```py
...
class FooStub(Foo):
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("In another fake method")
        assert True

        # Optionally, you can also call the real method if you want. You may update the arguments as needed.
        # super().bar(*args, **kwargs)

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("ray_fixture")
class FooTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
    def test_bar_remote(self):
        foo_actor = ray.remote(FooStub).remote()
        obj_ref = foo_actor.bar.remote()
        ray.get(obj_ref)
...
```

Output

```sh
$ pytest -q -rP
..
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________________________ FooTestCase.test_bar ___________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initializing ray
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
In fake method
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout teardown -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminating ray
_______________________________________________________________________________________ FooTestCase.test_bar_remote _______________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout setup ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Initializing ray
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout teardown -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Terminating ray
2 passed, 1 warning in 5.03s
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a below hacky way which involves change in original function (and check env variable to provide test implementation)

```
import os
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

    def bar(self):
        self.value = 100
        if os.environ.get['TEST'] == 'True':
           print("In fake method")
           assert True
        else:    
           print("In original method")
           assert False
```

```
runtime_env = {"env_vars": {"TEST": "True"}}
    
ray.remote(Foo) .options(runtime_env=runtime_env) .remote()
```